# I want to insert two forms into a database, one to create a table and the other to insert data but its not inserting into the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Please help me guys. This is the php code, the first one creates the table and the second code inserts data into the database but its not getting access to the variable.

```
   <?php
   $con= mysqli_connect              ('localhost','root','adminadmin','votes');
    $save;
    if(isset($_POST['save'])){
   $save=$_POST['cate'];

   $tl="CREATE TABLE $save (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY     KEY auto_increment,
     name varchar (60) NOT NULL,
    category varchar (60) NOT NULL)";

    mysqli_query($con, $tl);
    }else{
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $cate=$_POST['categ'];


        $sql= "INSERT INTO $save (name, category) VALUES     ('$name','$cate')";


        mysqli_query($con, $sql);
   }
   }
   ?>

    <form method="POST" action="try.php">

    <label>Enter category</label>
   <input type="text" name="cate" ></input>
   <button type="submit" name="save">save</button>
   </form>

    <form method="POST" action="try.php">


   <label>Enter name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ></input>
    <label>Enter category</label>
   <input type="text" name="categ" ></input>

    <button type="submit" name="submit">save</button>
    </form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are missing value for $save in insert query.

Comment: I dont understand

Answer (score 0):

Your if/else clause only allows the table to be created (if first condition applies), `else` would contain the insertion of data but won't get executed...

Comment: What can i do, if i have to remove the else if statement

Comment: just don't do an `else`part, but merge both into the `if` clause (i.e. IF there is input submitted)

Comment: Ok. Please can you correct me and post the code. Thanks